# Copy files from SD Card

Tags: windows-7, sd-card

I have a brand new 4GB SanDisc SD card.

With lot of personal files. (jpg, exe, zip, rar, doc...)

When I insert card in my notebook internal reader... first I get this message.

[image]

Then, if I want to copy files to e.g. desktop... first 5% of copy progress it's fine. But then it's get stuck!

[image]

More info:

[image]

Problem is that files are my only copy. Usually I would just formatt the SD Card.

**Edit:**
"Initial message", repeats randomly while trying to copy files

Comment: So, you are able to write to the SD card, but not read (on the same computer)?

Comment: Maybe you SD card has failed. I'd use the Linux 'dd' utility to get a block-by-block dump of the contents and then attempt to work with that. If stuck in Windows, you could try just using Scandisk and hope it's a simple file system error that it can fix. If your card is damaged, then each access could make the damage far worse (which is why you want to 'dd' a potentially dead device)

Comment: I can read and write.. but when i try move a larger files from Card to PC... it get stuck! Time remaining... 7 hours, etc.

Comment: With other SD (micro) Cards... I got no problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SD card seems to have been corrupted. Do not write to it before formatting, or it may become more corrupted, and I wouldn't trust it even after formatting.

I would suggest to use disk-recovery software to try and save your files.

See this article [Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm),
which recommends one of :

- [MiniTool Power Data Recovery](http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/)
- [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)
- [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page). Actually I always carry a version on a bootable usb stick.

Grap a copy and either make a cd or usb boot stick and boot your machine with it. 
There should be enough info on the site to get going.

After boot insert the SD card to you machine and type 
    blkid

You'll see lines like these. Identify you sdcard and the relevant part for later is the /dev/sdXX 
It will most likely be /dev/sdb or /dev/sdb1

```
/dev/sde1: LABEL="SYSRESC" UUID="6FA4-437A" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sde2: LABEL="KINGSTON" UUID="7590-DD1A" TYPE="vfat"
```

Then mount some drive with enough space to hold your full sdcard. See [sysresc](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Mounting_an_NTFS_partition_with_full_Read-Write_support) site for more info how to mount your drives as writable.

```
ddrescue /dev/sdXX /path/to/mountedDrive/filename.img
```

or (can't remember which I normally use.. both should work)

```
dd_rescue /dev/sdXX /path/to/mountedDrive/filename.img
```

replace /dev/sdXX with your drive (e.g. /dev/sdb1) and the latter with the path you mounted and a filename you want to giver your image-copy.

This might take some time and it will try to workaround bad block and io-errors.

To access your data you can do this:

```
mkdir /tmp/loop
mount -oloop,ro /path/to/mountedDrive/filename.img /tmp/loop
ls /tmp/loop
```

or if you have a new sd.card with the same capasity this will copy it to the new sd card

```
dd if=/path/to/mountedDrive/filename.img of=/dev/sdXX
```

Again the sdXX is from blkid command. PLEASE note that this command is dangerous if you happpen to typo the /dev/sdXX part, because *it will erase the destination*

http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page

http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Mounting_an_NTFS_partition_with_full_Read-Write_support

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the shift key when inserting the card to disable auto-play; that may help with the initial error message.

Look through the drive for compressed folders/zip archives - one of them is part of a multi-volume set.  If you don't know where that volume is, that archive file is useless.